# Difference between referencing System by itself and System along with System.Xml.Linq in project.config and csproj files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, csproj

What's the difference between referencing `System` in my `.csproj`file and referencing `System`, `System.Xml`, and `System.Xml.Linq`?

Some backstory:
Using Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.4.4, I decided to upgrade the NuGet packages that my projects were using. Post-upgrade, I noticed that my `packages.config` and `.csproj` files now contain "extra" entries.
 For example, previously my `.csproj` files contained (among other things) a simple line that stated:

```
<Reference Include="System" />,
```

but now, post upgrade, they also include the lines

```
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
```

Likewise, my project.config files gained entries like:

```
<package id="System.Xml.Linq"... >
```

that previously did exist.

Creating a test solution, <del>I wrote a small function that used a LINQ select statement</del>, printed an enum that lives in `System.Xml.Linq`, and then manually removed the `<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>` in the `.csproj` file, and everything seemed to compile normally.

So why were these extra entries automatically added? Do they serve a purpose?

Comment: do a google search on the system.xml.linq vs system.xml and read the difference.. do you understand what Linq is ? what it is used for.. this may help you to understand quickly what one is used for vs the other

Comment: Hi, I do understand the difference between `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq`. However, my query is more about the `.csproj` and `packages.config` file: If `System` is referenced already, why is `System.Xml.Linq` needed, especially when removing the reference does not affect the build.

Comment: if you are not using any `linq` then remove it.. if you are not using any `xml` remove it..by default the project adds them if you use the wizard..

Comment: I am using LINQ, but apparently removing the reference to `System.Xml.Linq` in my `csproj` file had no ill effects (as noted in my initial query), as long as I still had a reference to `System`.

Answer (score 1):

> why were these extra entries automatically added? Do they serve a purpose?

Not sure why your `packages.config` files contain "extra" entry `<package id="System.Xml.Linq"... >`, may be error added or added as dependency for some packages (*if you want to dig deeper into the reason for this issue, you should find out why this package added*).

Generally, when you create a .NET framework project, the following .NET framework references would be added by default:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
```

Then you open the package `System.Xml.Linq`, you will find the this package only include a .NET framework 2.0 lib:

[image]

After install this package by nuget, the following lines will add into your project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Xml.Linq.3.5.21022.801\lib\net20\System.Xml.Linq.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

But if we install this package, above lines will replace the line `<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>`. Not sure why it not replace that line.

So that is the reason why you remove the reference to `System.Xml.Linq` in your `.csproj` file had no ill effects, Visual Studio still get the dll from the package.